# The ! operator in Javascript turns true to false an viceversa right?

Tags: javascript, operators

Learning Javascript, early beginner. I'm confused about the use of the ! operator in this bit of script:

```
  var switchDirection = false;

    function doAnimation() {
        var divAdvert = document.getElementById("divAdvert");
        var currentLeft = divAdvert.offsetLeft;
        var newLocation;

        if (!switchDirection) {
            newLocation = currentLeft + 2;

            if (currentLeft >= 400) {
                switchDirection = true;
            }
        }
```

It's not complete but it's a simple bidirectional sliding text. The logic as I understand it is: if switchDirection is false, add 2 pixels to currentLeft and store it in newLocation.

The thing is if switchDirection was initialized as false, then why (!switchDirection) still returns false? I thought the ! operator turned it to true.

(!switchDirection) is the same as (switchDirection == false). The second statement I completely understand, but the first doesn't get into my thick skull.

Comment: __NO..__ If inverse of `switchDirection` is `==` true then... So in your case, it is being evaluated as `true` hence `if` condition is being satisfied!

Comment: can you add some console logs before and after the if statement and post the output here

Comment: try to check `switchDirection` the value of it might have change to true 
before it goes to the `if condition` , in this code `if (currentLeft >= 400) {switchDirection = true;}` where are you setting the value of switchDirection to false again after this?

Comment: when you invoke the `doAnimation()` on the second time.. `switchDirection` is already true if it goes to the condition `if (currentLeft >= 400)` or unless you reset the value to false.

Comment: *Comparing* a value to a boolean is different than *converting* a value to a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` always executes the block if the condition passed to it(in this case `!switchDirection`) is truthy.

`!switchDirection` evaluates to !false, i.e. `true`.

Hence `!switchDirection` is not same as `switchDirection == false`.

Another point you seem to be confused at is how `!` operator works. The `!` operator doesn't actually modify the original value. It just returns the negated value. Hence in this case, `!switchDirection` returns `false` but the value of `switchDirection` remains true in `if` condition. `switchDirection` is explicitly set to `true` later in your code.

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered how the negations work, if you want to implement other method in order to clear the confusion, there's also an enum in javascript:

```
var Direction = {
    LEFT: 1,
    RIGHT: 2
};

var switchDirection = Direction.LEFT;

    function doAnimation() {
        var divAdvert = document.getElementById("divAdvert");
        var currentLeft = divAdvert.offsetLeft;
        var newLocation;

        if (switchDirection == LEFT) {
            newLocation = currentLeft + 2;

            if (currentLeft >= 400) {
                switchDirection = Direction.RIGHT;
            }
        }
```

Or even better use an `Object.freeze()` in the enum:

```
var Direction = Object.freeze({LEFT: 1, RIGHT:2})
```

Comment: Thanks, although your sample is more advanced due to the use of objects, I understand it better than the code I posted originally.